# Minecraft PE Realm on iPad

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition, minecraft-bedrock-edition-realms

When I click Minecraft Realms on my iPad I get booted out.  I cannot login.  I paid for an Realms subscription... what did I do wrong?

Comment: PC.. not iOS. Realms subscriptions are **only for the PC**. | The realms on iOS are a alpha (or was that beta?) test and was recently closed down.

Comment: But I see Realm on my iPad apps... what is that for?

Comment: It's a separate service that has shut down.. And from what I heard, it hasn't gone past beta (or alpha; forgot) testing.

Comment: dang  I paid for realms subs so I can play on my iPad and with my kids

Answer (score 1):

Realms Mobile was shut down, unfortunately, due to the developers wanting to focus on the single player gameplay. However, you can still play LAN games, and when it comes out, online multiplayer.

Answer (score 0):

Realms were on the MCPE a while ago but were removed because they wanted to focus on updating the game and not on multiplayer.